# ImportError: No module named compat on importing nltk.compat import defaultdict

Tags: python, nltk

Hi i am using nltk and currently nltk is updated on the system.

However i get this error

```
ImportError: No module named compat
```

when i try to import

```
from nltk.compat import defaultdict
```

remaining nltk is working fine.

I am trying to use train() method within my file. that is why i need to import this.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Your syntax is wrong. There is no `import foo import bar`, You probably mean `from nltk import defaultdict` and `from nltk import compat`

Comment: Yup sorry, i mean from nltk.compat import defaultdict

Comment: `defaultdict` is not under `nltk.compat` but `nltk`. See my answer…

Comment: btw i used "from collections import defaultdict" and works fine. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Of course, `defaultdict` is under `collections` but `nltk` has either it's own or is importing it from `collections`.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong. Use the `from foo import bar` syntax like this:

```
>>> from nltk import compat
>>> from nltk import defaultdict
```

Comment: I used "from collections import defaultdict" and works fine. Thanks for the input.